# Want to access lexically defined functions using EVAL in CLISP

Tags: clisp

Why won't this piece of code work?

```
(setf x '(foo bar (baz)))

(labels 
    ((baz () (print "baz here"))) 
    (baz) ;works
    (eval (third x))) ;fails with the below message

*** - EVAL: undefined function BAZ
```

I'm using GNU CLISP.

Comment: Make sure to include the error message(s)/symptom(s) of "doesn't work". These can be used for further refine the question/title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Common Lisp, `eval` evaluates its argument in a null lexical environment, so your lexically bound function `baz` can't be found.

While the Common Lisp standard doesn't provide a portable way to access the lexical environment and invoke eval with it, your implementation might have this functionality. For example, in CLISP:

```
cs-user> (setf x '(foo bar (baz)))

(foo bar (baz))
cs-user> (labels ((baz () (print "baz here"))) 
           (eval-env (third x) (the-environment)))

"baz here" 
"baz here"
cs-user>
```

See geocar's answer for other approaches.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for! Thanks Danlei!

Comment: I'm selecting this as an answer because I'm on CLISP and this looks like the easiest to digest from a noob's perspective

Comment: You're welcome. One easy portable solution would be to use a separate package for the functions, as geocar suggests below. Maybe – especially since you say you're a beginner – you should also rethink your design in general. I never needed to use eval like this, but that depends on what you really want to do. (But that should go into a separate question. I just answered the question at hand here without considering your possible use case.)

Answer (score 2):

## Because common lisp doesn't have special functions.

Check the description of [`EVAL`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eval.htm):

> Evaluates *form* in the current [dynamic environment](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_d.htm#dynamic_environment) and the [null lexical environment](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_n.htm#null_lexical_environment).

Since the lexical environment is empty, your `baz` function (defined by `labels`) isn't accessible. You'd think you could fix this by putting `baz` in the dynamic environment (you might want something like `(declare (special baz))` or `(declare (special (function baz)))` or something like this) but alas: there's no way to do this.

#### You could simulate it yourself by creating:

```
(defvar baz* nil)
(defun baz (&rest args) (apply baz* args))
```

You then need to dynamically set `baz*` instead of using `labels`:

```
(setf x '(foo bar (baz)))
(let ((baz* (lambda () (print "baz here"))))
  (eval (third x)))
```

**The reason why is just some hard bits about optimisation leaking into the spec.** Basically, every function-call would need some stubbing unless the compiler could *prove* that the function would never get defined dynamically swizzleable. That's hard to do efficiently, and it's not something most CL programmers ever did, so the spec-writers simply forbade it.

As you can see, and as with most things in CL, you can easily get it yourself if you need it. However. Given that most CL programmers never do this, you may want to re-examine why you're trying to do things this way.

Comment: Thank you geocar. Two reasons why I ended up with this code layout -- I'm dynamically building X from various sources and each entry in this list happens to have a list of functions I want to evaluate later at some point. The 'labels' was to define functions so I don't end up polluting the package (as I foresee lots of small functions). I'm still trying to digest the reasons you mention this is hard but I thought Lisp looks at lexical scope first and then moves up the chain. Have I got this completly wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have this completely wrong, but I can appreciate why it may not be obvious. Try to imagine how you would write your program in C: You'll find that your routine effectively becomes an interpreter and the nonstandard solution given by danlei only works *because* clisp is an interpreter. If you're comfortable having a slow interpreter, then that's fine, but if you're not comfortable with that, CL offers many options: You can use packages, you can write your own interpreter just for this part, you could use macrolet+macroexpand to force the dynamic state to be captured, and so on.